# How Can I Reduce Lines with Using Switch-Case Properly

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Blackjack game project. I have a `helper()`method for helping user for their acts. For example:

dealer's up card is: `8`
player's hand total is: `16`

Player is not sure, should he hit or stay. `helper()` function takes action in here.

It's basically counts the number of good cards on deck (`playerTotal` + `goodcard` <= 21)

So I'm thinking about to do it in this way (pseudo code)

```
public void helper() {

    remain = 21 - playerTotal;

    if (remain == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.last(); i++) {
            switch (deck[i]) {
                case A: numOfGood += 1
                default: numOfBad +=1
            }
        }
    }
    else if (remain == 2) {
        for (....) {
            switch (deck[i]) {
                case A: numOfGood += 1
                case 2: numOfGood += 1
                default: numOfBad +=1
            }
        }
    }

//goes like this

}
```

I need to build a switch-case and for loop for all cards(A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,J,K,Q,K) but it seems like a huge mess. How can I reduce the number of lines by doing something different?

Comment: You should probably worry more about your indentation than number of lines at this stage...

Comment: @BoltClock I don't know, writing out functionally the same large switch statement 20 times, but slightly varying which variable gets incremented in each `case` seems pretty worrisome; about as bad as the indentation...

Comment: @BoltClock  sorry for indentation I'm not in my own computer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First write a `GetValue` method that can compute the (minimum) numeric value for a card.  You can implement it with a `switch` or however else you want:

```
public static int GetValue(char card)
{
    //...
}
```

Once you have that the implementation of your method becomes *far* shorter and simpler:

```
foreach(var card in deck)
    if(GetValue(card) <= remain)
        numOfGood++;
    else
        numOfBad++;
```

Also note that you could just count the number of good *or* bad cards, and use the total remaining cards to compute the other, if needed.

```
var oddsOfSuccessfulHit = deck.Count(card => GetValue(card) <= remain) / 
    (double) deck.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashSet`, its probably a little more efficient to use a `switch` but if you want to save lines ...

```
var goodCards = new HashSet<char>(new[] { 'A', '2' });
```

then something like,

```
var numOfGood = deck.Count(card => goodCards.Contains(card));
var numOfBad = deck.Count - numOfGood;
```

Comment: A `switch` is going to be implemented as a hash-based table structure if there is more than a certain number of items in the set.  It's more efficient *not* to do this if the set is small enough.  Additionally, the code would still be *super* tedious and error prone even after this refactor, given that the operation needs to be listed out 20 times with only slight variations for each.

Comment: @Servy I'm not actually sure what the OP want to achieve, somthing to do with 21/Pontoon/Blackjack.

Comment: He has an `if/else if` chain with 20 different conditional checks (to cover the case of the remaining points being 1..20) and in each one he has a `switch` that has a case for each card with a value less than the remaining points represented in that case.  This does indeed shorten the `switch`, but doesn't deal with the 20-part `if/else if` chain that could be implemented with a single subtraction operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively since the logic of card values cannot change, there is no need to code it - just store it as data.

```
struct CardEffect
{
    public string CardGlyph;
    public int MinValue;
    public int MaxValue;
}

... load from XML file or some other location and load into ...
public Dictionary<string, CardEffect> cardValues;
```

Then use the logic Servy has suggested.

Comment: The second two values are entirely derived data of the first, and should not be stored independently.  The only actual field of such a class should be the card itself; the numeric value that corresponds to it should be a property/field that computes the value based on the other.  Of course, you could reverse this and actually store the numeric value instead, but by having both as fields you allow for invalid data to exist, such as a King that is worth 25 points.  Additionally, *mutable structs are evil*.

Comment: @Servy - I'd disagree. Why put into code something which is plainly data ? The relationship between a card Glyph and its value is a data relationship, whereas applying that data to a card hand is a logical relationship. Express logic in code and data in data structures; its clear, clean and extensible. I used the simplist structure to explain the approach - sure you could protect the Setter for the values making it immutable, but would that really make the proposed answer clearer ?

Comment: You would put code into the type so that you can abstract away the logic of getting the value for a card, *which is the whole point here*.  Getting the numerical value for a card is *logic*.  It is the logic of the game BlackJack.  No value is added to the program at all by using this structure, and a fair bit is lost in the (rather significant) potential for errors or mistakes in settings the values.  Creating a `Card` type that *can* actually abstract away a portion of logic on how to perform various operations on a Card could certainly have value.